# Listening for exchange events using brownie

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, brownie

**I'm trying to find a way to listen for uniswap pricing 'infinitely' then code some logic to possibly arb between different exchanges**.*Please link me to any relevant projects if possible*

**I used the example at** https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html#examples-listening-for-events

**but made some modifications**

```
# import the following dependencies
import json
from web3 import Web3
import asyncio
import time

# add your blockchain connection information
infura_url = 'https://eth-kovan.alchemyapi.io/v2/55qP7HQoArbIJEMSfDgdcVEdXOqn_-et'
web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(infura_url))

# uniswap address and abi
uniswap_router = '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D'
uniswap_factory = '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f'
uniswap_factory_abi = json.loads('[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token0","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"token1","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"PairCreated","type":"event"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"allPairs","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"allPairsLength","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenA","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"tokenB","type":"address"}],"name":"createPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"pair","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeTo","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"feeToSetter","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"getPair","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeTo","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeTo","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_feeToSetter","type":"address"}],"name":"setFeeToSetter","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]')

contract = web3.eth.contract(address=uniswap_factory, abi=uniswap_factory_abi)
#greeting_Event = contract.events.greeting() # Modification
event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')

# define function to handle events and print to the console
def handle_event(event):
    receipt = web3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(event['transactionHash'])
    result = event_filter.processReceipt(receipt) # Modification
    print(result[0]['args'])


# asynchronous defined function to loop
# this loop sets up an event filter and is looking for new entires for the "PairCreated" event
# this loop runs on a poll interval
def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for event in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(event)
            time.sleep(poll_interval)


# when main is called
# create a filter for the latest block and look for the "PairCreated" event for the uniswap factory contract
# run an async loop
# try to run the log_loop function above every 2 seconds
def main():
    event_filter = contract.events.PairCreated.createFilter(fromBlock='latest')
    block_filter = web3.eth.filter({'fromBlock':'latest', 'address':uniswap_factory})
    tx_filter = web3.eth.filter('pending')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(
            asyncio.gather(
            log_loop(event_filter, 2)
            
            ))
        log_loop(block_filter, 2),
        log_loop(tx_filter, 2)
    finally:
        # close loop to free up system resources
        loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Running this simply halts the terminal.What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using brownie running on ethereum mainnet. It subscribes to the Sync event of the UniswapV2Pair contract. This event is emitted by the contract when there has been an update in the reserve balances (when a trade has been made). Of course, make sure you have the https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Pair.sol file in your project's interfaces directory.

```
import asyncio
from web3 import Web3
from brownie import interface


def main():
    weth_usdc_pair_addr = "0xB4e16d0168e52d35CaCD2c6185b44281Ec28C9Dc"
    contract = interface.IUniswapV2Pair(weth_usdc_pair_addr)
    event_filter = contract.events.Sync.createFilter(fromBlock="latest")
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    try:
        asyncio.run(log_loop(event_filter, 1))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(" Cancelled by user, exiting")
    finally:
        loop.close()


async def log_loop(event_filter, poll_interval):
    while True:
        for Sync in event_filter.get_new_entries():
            handle_event(Sync)
        await asyncio.sleep(poll_interval)


def handle_event(event):
    print(Web3.toJSON(event))
```